# How to check if any object is related to a row in a table with constrain of foreign key

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am using Hibernate and MySql.

I have a 2 tables:

```
User: id, name, type
City: id, name, type
type: id, name
```

Where user.type has foreign key to user_type.id. and as well city.

I would like before deleting a row in user_type table, to check if any row from any table is related to it.

my columns are mapped for example:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "type_id")
```

How can I do it?

Comment: How are your tables mapped? I mean is this relation reflected in the mapping? Since Hibernate can check that for you and can cascade the deletion or whatever you need.

Comment: I edited my question with the mapping

Comment: Will mySQL anyway let you delete a row in table Type if its related?? It will through an exception wouldn't it (Since it is a type_id is foreign key related)??

Comment: it will throw an excpetion. But I would like to know it before it throws any exception

Comment: If possible, let me know what you have done as workaround. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said

> I have **around 100 tables** like User and City mapped to this value

ok. Hibernate with JPA book says

> You may have removed all other references **manually**

Which implies you should query **manually** any related Table. But it says if other entity references Type, database constraints prevent any inconsistency and **you see a foreign key constraint exception**. I Think it is the best way you can check out what you want. Otherwise, you should query manually for any related Table.

```
try {
    userType = (Type) session.load(Type.class, id);

    session.delete(userType);
/**
  * or JDBCException 
  * e.getCause()
  * e.getErrorCode() - vendor-specific
  */
} catch (HibernateException e) {
    // checkout Exception right here e.getCause();
}
```

All exceptions thrown by Hibernate **are fatal**. This means you **have to roll back** the database transaction and close the current Session. So you may want To open a new session.

Answer (score 0):

use native SQL with Hibernate together:

```
  boolean canDeleteType(ind type_id){
         Session s = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(); 
         s.beginTransaction();
         Query q = s.createQuery("SELECT User.type_id From User");
         List l = q.list();

    if(l.contains(type_id){
   return false;
}
return false;

}
```

and do the same for your City table too.